# Android Studio Project is out of Date warning when running test with coverage

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, build.gradle, code-coverage

I keep getting this warning when running test with coverage.(Kotlin codebase)

[image]

Recompile will fail and this warning dialog will show again. However, the code coverage is available and updated. It's just really annoying to see the dialog every time I run the tests.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: IMHO, Code coverage is broken for years on Android.